# Properties of Schwartz functions

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity, schwartz-space

Let $f$ in [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), and $K, \gamma >0$.
Then I guess the following:
\begin{align}
\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \left| f(x) \right| dx } +\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \left| f(x) \right| dx } &=\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \frac { x }{ x } \left| f(x) \right| dx } +\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \frac { x }{ x } \left| f(x) \right| dx } \\ &\le { \left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } +{ \left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } \\ &={ -\left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ -\gamma  }^{ -k }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } +{ \left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } \\ &={ -\left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } +{ \left\| f \right\|  }_{ 1,0 }\int _{ \gamma  }^{ k }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } \\ &=0
\end{align}

I did this calculation but I think that I am wrong or maybe not, Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this would be correct if and only if $f$ vanishes on both intervals $(-k,-\gamma)$ and $(\gamma,k)$.

The problem is in the first inequality: on $(-k,-\gamma)$, $x$ is negative hence the integral $\int_{-k}^{-\gamma}1/x\mathrm dx$ should be $-\int_{-k}^{-\gamma}1/x\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me a litle bit more?. In this integral, I put x<0. $\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \left| f(x) \right| dx }=\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \left| f(x) \right| dx } \le C\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx } $ . if I set x<0.  Why do you change the sign in the last integral?

Comment: But we only know that $\left\lvert x\right\rvert \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\leqslant C$ hence the bound should be $C\int _{ -k }^{ -\gamma  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \left\lvert x\right\rvert  } dx }$.